# file:// and spaces in filenames

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've been debugging a curious issue with file paths in an instance of IE embedded in my application.

I have the following JavaScript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foobar(src) {
  $("img").attr("src", src);
}
</script>
```

And my DOM contains a single `img` tag:

```
<img src="loading.jpg" />
```

I have the following three links which call `foobar` when activated:

```
<a href="javascript:foobar('file:///C:/nospaces/someimage.bmp');">without spaces</a>
<a href="javascript:foobar('file:///C:/path spaces/someotherimage.bmp');">with spaces</a>
<a href="javascript:foobar('file:///C:/path%20spaces/someotherimage.bmp');">with spaces</a>
```

All of those links work great in IE/FF/Chrome, but only the first link works in my application where I'm using an embedded instance of IE.

If I right-click the image after clicking the second link (one of the two that doesn't work, the third one gives the exact same results), I can see the image URL is this:

```
file://C:\path%20spaces\someotherimage.bmp
```

which doesn't load if I paste that address into Start->Run.

Changing the address to add a third `/` after `file:`, like this:

```
file:///C:\path%20spaces\someotherimage.bmp
```

allows Start->Run to open the image.

Interestingly, non-embedded IE retains all 3 slashes (`file:///`), so all three links work.

Has anyone come across this sort of issue? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried perhaps encoding the spaces in your original URL? Or using onclick instead of href="javascript:... to trigger the action? IE has a long history of weirdness when it comes to handling slightly-malformed URLs, and since that service is provided by a system DLL it doesn't surprise me that an embedded system might be using an older / alternate version of that.

Comment: @Shog9 - thanks for your suggestions - I'd tried `%20` already, I've now tried `onclick` - no luck. I hate the last 5 hours.

Comment: @Shog9 - pinging you in case you're curious - I solved the problem below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was due to the HTML being specified one [URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) (a proprietary one), and the images being specified in another (the [File URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Internet_Explorer)).

Changing them both to use `file:///` fixed the problem.

That said, I still have no idea why paths without spaces worked, whilst path with spaces didn't. If anyone has any idea why (preferably with an authoritative source if there is one) - feel free to post it as an answer and I'll give you the accept.

Comment: Hrm... IE is weird. If your proprietary scheme was implemented as a pluggable handler, then I suppose it may have had a bug in its implementation of the routine such handlers provide to resolve relative URLs; otherwise, I suspect the system routine had the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of testing perhaps try:

```
foobar('file:///C:/path+spaces/someotherimage.bmp');
```